# How to configure maven local and remote repository in gradle build file?

Tags: maven, gradle

i want to use the maven local repository additionally to a maven remote one. I found the JIRA-Issue http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1173 for that, but adapting my gradle build file in that way some snapshot dependencies which are only available in the local maven repository are still not found. I get an error that the Snapshot-Dependency is not found.

Is it possible to have one local and one remote maven repository?

Here is the relevant part of my gradle build file:

```
apply plugin: 'maven'

repositories {

    mavenLocal()

    maven {
        credentials {
            username "myusername"
            password "mypassword"
        }
        url "http://myremoterepository"
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see a reason why it shouldn't work. Can you try temporarily excluding remote maven repository and relevant dependencies and see what happens? It's possible that `mavenLocal()` is not guessing the location of the repository correctly. Try explicitly pointing it to the right place with `mavenRepo urls: "file:///home/user/.m2/repository"` instead of `mavenLocal()` and see what happens.

Comment: Be aware that `X.Y-SNAPSHOT` is always _older_ than `X.Y` so when you add the `-SNAPSHOT` also bump `Y` in preparation for an eventual release.  If you just add `-SNAPSHOT` to an already published `X.Y` then it will find the `X.Y` not the `X.Y-SNAPSHOT`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I also needed to do a similar setup with my project and I can verify your build.gradle setup works provided your Maven is setup correctly.

*Gradle*'s `mavenLocal()` relies on the `localRepository` definition from the *maven* [`settings.xml`](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html) file:

```
  <localRepository>USER_HOME\.m2\repository</localRepository>
```

The settings.xml should be in either your `M2_HOME/conf` or your `USER_HOME/.m2 directory`. You should check:

1. *maven* is installed correctly
2. `M2_HOME` environment variable exists
3. `settings.xml` has the correct `localRepository` defined..

Comment: Some people override local maven repository location (for example in IDE). So I'd prefer to put explicit location for maven repo: `maven {
        url uri(local_repository_path)
    }` where `local_repository_path` is taken from `gradle.properties`

Comment: Does anybody know what environment variables I have to configure on Windows? my maven installation is in the path, I have an einvironment variable M2_HOME pointing to the folder where settings.xml is located, maven itself resolves the repository just fine, but gradle doesn't. It builds when I do publishToMavenLocal, but nothing shows up in the repository.

Comment: @UncleBob I had the same problem, put `<localRepository>${user.home}/.m2/repository</localRepository>` in your `~/.m2/setttings.xml` (tilda means USER_HOME, e.g. `C:\Users\UncleBob`)

Answer (score 0):

Maven can only use a single local ("local" = on the harddisk of the computer on which Maven runs) repository.

If you need more, you're options are:

- Run a remote server (like a company wide proxy) and deploy everything there. Put that server as a mirror into your `settings.xml`.
- Run `mvn install` to copy the artifacts in your local repo (obviously only when you do have the sources)
- Run a local server
- Copy the artifacts manually into your local repo

Comment: One single local is enough for me - one single and one remote maven respository, not multiple local maven repositories

Comment: In that case, edit your question and add this information: what error do you get for the snapshot artifacts?