# mvn install from gradle

Tags: maven, gradle, integration

I have a created a gradle project and a different project was created in Maven.

The jar from the maven project is a dependency to the gradle project.

Is it possible to run the mvn install for the maven project and add the jar to the gradle project?

Thanks & Regards
Mukund

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383521/how-to-configure-maven-local-and-remote-repository-in-gradle-build-file

Answer (score 1):

All that's needed on the Gradle side is:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    compile "some.group:someArtifact:1.0"
}
```