# Why can't Gradle see this Maven co-ordinate in the local m2 repository?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, build.gradle

I have a few locally built JAR files from an internal library.  Tonight's task is to convert an existing (working) Maven project to use a Gradle build.  I can successfully link with Apache-commons3 in the same repository and as far as I can see the Maven coordinates are formed in the same way.

Starting small, I attempted to compile a small main program with the locally built "Util.jar":

```
  dependencies{

    //          -- local lib --
compile group: 'lib.java8', name: 'util',  version: '00.08.007'

    //          -- apache commons --
compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.3.2'
  }
```

In the repository folder area, the file versions between the local library JAR and Apache appear congruent to me.  First the library ...

```
 Directory of r:\.repo\maven\.m2\repository\local\lib\java8\util\00.08.007

    07-Jun-2015  21:20            20,585 util-00.08.007.jar
    27-Apr-2015  21:03             1,829 util-00.08.007.pom
```

And the Apache-commons entry in the same repository:

```
 Directory of r:\.repo\maven\.m2\repository\local\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.3.2

 16-Dec-2014  21:48           412,739 commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar
 16-Dec-2014  21:48                40 commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar.sha1
 16-Dec-2014  21:48            20,377 commons-lang3-3.3.2.pom
 16-Dec-2014  21:48                40 commons-lang3-3.3.2.pom.sha1
 09-May-2015  23:12               261 _maven.repositories
 17-Sep-2014  19:31               199 _remote.repositories
```

To my eye the file name-versionNumber-s of both examples are structured alike.  However the

```
gradle assemble
```

Goal reports errors on the locally compiled library JAR.

**gradle assemble** ...

```
  :compileJava

  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

  * What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
  > Could not find lib.tmacs.java8:util:00.08.007.
    Searched in the following locations:
        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/lib/java8/util/00.08.007/util-00.08.007.pom
        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/lib/java8/util/00.08.007/util-00.08.007.jar
    Required by:
        :dataexample:00.00.001-SNAPSHOT

  BUILD FAILED
```

I am stumped.  In each case the repository file matched coordinated in the same way.

QUESTION:

1. What does Gradle look for that (working) Maven projects don't?
2. Can I access the existing `Util.jar` with Gradle and How?
3. How do I fix the Maven POM that builds the `Util.jar` library so that both new Gradle projects and existing Maven POM projects can build with the same JAR??

Finally, am I asking the right questions, or am I completely off track?

Comment: Gradle links projects using a different coordinate dsl. For a locally installed dependency, you probably forgot to add `mavenLocal()` to your repositories section so that Gradle looks in the .m2 folder.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle has already given you the answer:

> Searched in the following locations:
>
> https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/lib/java8/util/00.08.007/util-00.08.007.pom
>
> https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/lib/java8/util/00.08.007/util-00.08.007.jar

You need to instruct gradle where to look for your artifacts. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383521/how-to-configure-maven-local-and-remote-repository-in-gradle-build-file) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32958928/how-to-configure-gradle-to-find-local-snapshot-resource). The keyword of interest there is `mavenLocal()`.

All information about defining repositories can be found in [the docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html)